# Lines joining two sequences of numbers

Tags: plotting, graphics, data

I have two sequences of numbers, for example

```
A={0, 1/5, 1/4, 1/3, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 2/3, 3/4, 4/5, 1}

B={0, 1/10, 1/5, 3/10, 2/5, 1/2, 3/5, 7/10, 4/5, 9/10, 1}
```

and I want a diagram or graphic to join first term from A to first of B, i.e. {0,0}, the second of A to the second of B,... up to {1,1}. Also if possible I like to have bold point in the vertices joining each pairs.

I put here example did with MS paint.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = Thread[{A, 0}];
b = Thread[{B, 1}];

ListLinePlot[Transpose[{a, b}], PlotStyle -> Thick, Joined -> True, 
 Epilog -> {PointSize[Medium], Point /@ {a, b}}]
```

[image]

```
ListLinePlot[Transpose[{a, b}], PlotStyle -> Thick, Joined -> True, 
 Epilog -> {EdgeForm[Gray], White, Disk[#, Offset[5]] & /@ Join[a, b]}, 
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/5, PlotRangePadding -> {{.05, .05}, {.1, .1}}]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `Graphics`:

```
Graphics[{Thick, MapIndexed[{ColorData[97]@#2[[1]], Line@#} &, Transpose[{a, b}]], 
  EdgeForm[Gray], White, Disk[#, Offset[5]] & /@ Join[a, b]}, 
 AspectRatio -> 1/5, Frame -> True, 
 PlotRangePadding -> {{.05, .05}, {.2, .2}}, ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]